# Laravel eloquant multiple join with WITH

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I don't know how to create `Laravel` `eloquent` join when I have multiple tables:

```
        Schema::create('released_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code', 10);
            $table->string('description');
          ***
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('code', 10);
            $table->string('description');
            ***
            $table->timestamps();
});

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recipe_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('fk_recipe_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('fk_released_items_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code', 10);
            $table->float('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();



            $table->foreign('fk_recipe_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('recipes')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('fk_released_items_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('released_items')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

I have 'Recipe' model:

```
  public function lines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\RecipeLine::class, 'fk_recipe_id');
    }
 public function released_item()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(\App\RecipeLine::class, 'fk_released_items_id');
    }
```

And RecipeLines Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $lines = Recipe::with('lines', 'released_item')->where('recipes.id', $id)->findOrFail($id);
}
```

But I still can't extract a data from released_items.
Anyone know hot it work and can explain?

Comment: `released_items` or `released_item`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga released_item

Comment: but `fk_released_items_id` is the column of `recipe_lines`. not `recipe`. And from the tables structure. It look like many-to-many relationship.And if `line` has-one `released_item`, then one `recipe` has-many `released_items`.

Comment: @TsaiKoga this is how it looks like. I have table released_items that's why fk_released_items_id. First join one to many one recipe to multiple lines and from second table I need to join line with released_item (table name: released_items)

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships is not setup correctly in your model. I understand a Recipe has one or more Recipe Line, but it is not clear if a Recipe has one Release Item OR if a Recipe Line has one Release Item.

Based on your comment below, the relationship below should be in your Recipe Line model, not the Recipe model:

```
public function released_item()
{
   return $this->hasOne(\App\ReleasedItem::class, 'fk_released_items_id');
}
```

Then your query should be something like below:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $lines = Recipe::with('lines.released_item)->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: Correct Recipe can have one or more lines and from lines i need to create another join to released items where one line have one released item